# Updating Accounts without the ID

Tags: lightning, soql, account, data, data-import

What would be the most efficient way to update an excel sheet with 400 accounts that do not have an ID nor external ID of accounts that exist in the system.

There are about 40,000 accounts in salesforce currently and I have to update 400 of these without the ID. Very few dupes are within the system out of these 400 accounts, so potentially something can be done with the Account Name.

Comment: The best way with your scenario would be to make your custom key comprise of "AccountName" + "Site". Normally these two fields are used in conjunction to make the account unique if no other key is provided.

Comment: can you query for these Accounts first?  That will get you the ids

Comment: The site does not look to be populated in any account. @cropredy I could potentially do a soql query where the name is in a set of account names based on the excel sheet records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the file as a CSV, then go to the [Data Import Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_import_wizard.htm&type=5), which allows you to map by Account Name.